# Can anyone help me to pass list of objects as a parameter to redirecting url to controller in asp.net core?

Tags: arrays, ajax, list, object, controller

Can anyone help me to pass list of objects as a parameter to redirecting url to controller in asp.net core ?
I tried some methods using ajax call. When I try to send list of objects as parameters to redirecting url and get in controller the count shows 0 always in contoller. Please help me I am new to  this

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
          $("#<%=btnGetAll.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                    var id = $('#<%=ddlStudent.ClientID%>').val();
                    $.ajax({
               
                        type: "GET",
                        datatype: "json",
                        url: "https://localhost:44399/api/User/GetAllStudents/",
               
                        success: function (result) {
                            window.location.href = "http://localhost:56700/GetStuDetails/?stulist=" + JSON.stringify(result);
                            return false;
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            console.log('Error');
                            alert("error");
                        },
                    });
                })
    });
```